# WGS84 coordinates transformation to Cartesian coordinates in C#

Tags: .net, geospatial, coordinate-transformation, nettopologysuite, dotspatial

i'm new to geographic coordinate systems. I'm looking for the code example which provide conversion of point and polygon which coordinates are represented in WGS84 coordinate system to cartesian coordinates. Because i want to use NetTopologySuite library to perform some geometry calculations like calculating distance from point to polygon.

Thank you!